# Post method not working after redirect in Django

Tags: python, django, redirect, view, location

I am trying to create a system where certain pages can't be accessed unless the request is from a specific location. I currently have everything working except after the location is checked and the request is redirected to the next view, the form on that next view isn't posting properly. It's still trying to post the location data form.

You'll see what I mean more in my `views.py`:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = StudentModelForm()
    context_data = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'add.html', context_data)


def location_check_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'lat' in request.POST:
        user_lat = request.POST.get('lat')
        user_lon = request.POST.get('lon')
        if good_location(user_lat,user_lon):
            return add(request)
        else:
            return render(request, 'location.html')
    return render(request, 'checking.html')
```

So I'm trying to redirect to the `add()` view if `good_location` is true. It redirects properly but then when a user tries to post the form on `add.html` django thinks it's submitting the form in `location_check_add` again.

Edit: Adding `urls.py` for reference

```
import users.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', users.views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^add/', users.views.location_check_add, name = 'add'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! After a lot of documentation searching and googling I found out about Django's sessions feature. Documentation here:

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#examples)

In the end my code ended up looking like:

```
def add(request):
    if request.session.get('at_work', False):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = StudentModelForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = StudentModelForm()
        context_data = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'add.html', context_data)
    else:
        return redirect(location_check_add)

def location_check_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'lat' in request.POST:
        user_lat = request.POST.get('lat')
        user_lon = request.POST.get('lon')
        if good_location(user_lat,user_lon):
            request.session['at_work'] = True
            return redirect(add)
        else:
            return render(request, 'location.html')
    return render (request, 'checking.html')
```

Basically I just passed around the session variable "at_work" to make sure the location was correct before rendering the page in the add() view. Then I was able to use the regular redirect function since I could have a url directed at add() in urls.py without people getting around the location check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect, not just call the view.

```
    if good_location(user_lat,user_lon):
        return redirect('add')
```

Comment: Right now I have it so that my website.com/add url directs to app.views.location_check_add. So when I tried "return redirect('add') it brought me back to the location check page. I have it this way right now so someone can't type website.com/add into the browser and skip right to "add.html" without the location check. Is there a better way to set this up? I'll add my urls.py to the original question for reference

Comment: Instead of calling users.views.location_check_add for the url add/ you can have just one view, where inside the view you first check for the location's validity then show the content if valid else don't show the content or redirect them to another error page or something !!

Comment: @ManjunathSatyamurthy So I tried your suggestion because it seems like the best way to go in this situation. But I'm still getting the same error where the first POST (in this case the coordinates form) keeps getting submitted even though it should be the add() form. I think it's because the first request.POST is getting forwarded along to the next view and it's not a brand new request like in a proper redirect.

Comment: Ohh don't call another view from with in a view !! If you are using javascript ajax post then you should manually detect the redirect and change the window.location manually. instead of redirecting to add view, render the add form !!